# Empty column values but keep values equal to the number provided using SQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server

Suppose the following table

```
ID         Name     RowNumber
2314       YY       1
213        XH       2
421        XD       3
123        AA       4
213        QQQ      5
12         WW       6
312        RR       7
123        GG       8
12         F        9
12         FF       10
312        VV       11
12         BB       12
32         NN       13
43         DD       14
53         DD       15
658        QQQQ     16
768        GGG      17
```

I want to replace the `Name` field with empty string based on condition that

1. First and Last cells value will not be removed.
2. Need to return values not in continuous cells.
3. Only n number of cells will be preserved
4. if n is less than or equal to the number entered by user than do nothing

For example, if user enters 5 then only 5 values will be preserved and the result should be (OR similar)-

```
ID         Name     RowNumber
2314       YY       1
213                 2
421                 3
123        AA       4
213                 5
12                  6
312                 7
123        GG       8
12                  9
12                  10
312                 11
12                  12
32         NN       13
43                  14
53                  15
658                 16
768        GGG      17
```

There could be more records than this.

I'm using SQL Server

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: What do you mean by "First and last cell"? tables are unsorted by nature, so "first" and "last" are meaningless unless an order is specified (using order by in your sql statement).

Comment: Suppose it is sorted by row number

Comment: Ok, what's the reason for keeping `AA`, `GG` and `NN`, instead of, for example, `QQQ`, FF` and `DD`?

Comment: It could be any string.

Comment: if n is less than or equal to the number entered by user than do nothing. [Updated the question]

Answer (score 1):

The following will work in SQL Server 2012+, because it uses running/cumulative `SUM`. The query assumes that values in `RowNumber` column are sequential from 1 to total row count without gaps. If your data is not like this, you can use `ROW_NUMBER` to generate them.

- Calculate Ratio of the given number `N` and total number of rows (`CTE_Ratio`)
- Calculate running sum of this Ratio, truncating the fractional part of the sum (`CTE_Groups`)
- Each integer value of the running rum defines a group of rows, re-number rows within each group (`CTE_Final`)
- Preserve `Name` only for the first row from each group

To understand better how it works include intermediate columns (Ratio, GroupNumber, rn) into the output

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9d3d97/2/0)

**Sample data**

```
DECLARE @T TABLE ([ID] int, [Name] varchar(50), [RowNumber] int);

INSERT INTO @T([ID], [Name], [RowNumber]) VALUES
(2314, 'YY', 1)
,(213, 'XH', 2)
,(421, 'XD', 3)
,(123, 'AA', 4)
,(213, 'QQQ', 5)
,(12, 'WW', 6)
,(312, 'RR', 7)
,(123, 'GG', 8)
,(12, 'F', 9)
,(12, 'FF', 10)
,(312, 'VV', 11)
,(12, 'BB', 12)
,(32, 'NN', 13)
,(43, 'DD', 14)
,(53, 'DD', 15)
,(658, 'QQQQ', 16)
,(768, 'GGG', 17);

DECLARE @N int = 5;
```

**Query**

```
WITH
CTE_Ratio AS
(
    SELECT
        ID
        ,Name
        ,RowNumber
        ,COUNT(*) OVER() AS TotalRows
        ,CAST(@N-1 AS float) / CAST(COUNT(*) OVER() AS float) AS Ratio
    FROM @T
)
,CTE_Groups AS
(
    SELECT
        ID
        ,Name
        ,RowNumber
        ,TotalRows
        ,ROUND(SUM(Ratio) OVER(ORDER BY RowNumber), 0, 1) AS GroupNumber
    FROM CTE_Ratio
)
,CTE_Final AS
(
    SELECT
        ID
        ,Name
        ,RowNumber
        ,TotalRows
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY GroupNumber ORDER BY RowNumber) AS rn
    FROM CTE_Groups
)
SELECT
    ID
    ,CASE WHEN rn=1 OR RowNumber = TotalRows THEN Name ELSE '' END AS Name
    ,RowNumber
FROM CTE_Final
ORDER BY RowNumber;
```

**Result**

```
+------+------+-----------+
|  ID  | Name | RowNumber |
+------+------+-----------+
| 2314 | YY   |         1 |
|  213 |      |         2 |
|  421 |      |         3 |
|  123 |      |         4 |
|  213 | QQQ  |         5 |
|   12 |      |         6 |
|  312 |      |         7 |
|  123 |      |         8 |
|   12 | F    |         9 |
|   12 |      |        10 |
|  312 |      |        11 |
|   12 |      |        12 |
|   32 | NN   |        13 |
|   43 |      |        14 |
|   53 |      |        15 |
|  658 |      |        16 |
|  768 | GGG  |        17 |
+------+------+-----------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
--Number that user enter
DECLARE @InputNumber INT
DECLARE @WorkingNumber INT
DECLARE @TotalRecords INT
DECLARE @Devider INT
SET @InputNumber = 5
SET @WorkingNumber = @InputNumber -2
--Assume @InputNumber greater than 2 and @TotalRecords greater than 4
SELECT @TotalRecords = COUNT(*)
FROM Table;

SET @Devider = CONVERT(@TotalRecords, DECIMAL(18,2))/CONVERT(@WorkingNumber, DECIMAL(18,2));

WITH Conditioned (RowNumber)
AS
(
 SELECT RowNumber
 FROM Table
 WHERE RowNumber = 1
 UNION
 SELECT T.RowNumber
 FROM (SELECT TOP 1 RowNumber
       FROM Conditioned
       ORDER BY RowNumber DESC) AS C
      INNER JOIN Table AS T ON CONVERT(CEILING(C.RowNumber + @Devider), INT) = T.RowNumber
)
SELECT T.Id, CASE WHEN C.RowNumber IS NULL THEN '' ELSE T.Name END, T.RowNumber
FROM Table T
 LEFT OUTER JOIN Conditioned C ON T.RowNumber = C.RowNumber
WHERE
UNION RowNumber != @TotalRecords
SELECT Id, Name, RowNumber
FROM Table
WHERE RowNumber = @TotalRecords
```

Comment: You have joined the table.. ID is not primary key as you can see the question..ID is not unique